# Reading datasets from files to lists

Tags: python, optimization, beginner

I'm working on a simple program and am trying to make it faster.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pp

first_file = open("ac_data.dat", 'r') #real dataset includes about 20000 terms
res_file = open("res.dat", 'w')
times_file = open("times.dat", 'a')

#times = [0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001000, 0.001500, 0.002000, 0.002500, 0.003000, 0.003500, 0.004000, 0.004500, 0.005000, 0.005500, 0.006000, 0.006500, 0.007000, 0.007500, 0.008000, 0.008500, 0.009000, 0.009500]
#magn = [-13.876622, -10.014824, -16.356894, -11.639914, -13.103313, -14.335239, -12.250072, -10.727098, -8.701272, -9.632907, -9.673712, -10.541722, -14.075446, -13.097790, -12.495679, -10.322924, -14.979391, -14.895666, -11.874325, -9.287736]

times = []
magn = []

for i in first_file:
  dat = [float(j) for j in i.split()]
  times.append(dat[0])
  magn.append(dat[1])

length = len(magn) #supposed to be equal 20000 for original data

#autocorrelation function
def rxx_func(amp):
    N = len(amp)
    rxx = [0]*N

    for m in xrange(N):
        for n in xrange(N-m):
            rxx[m]+=amp[n]*amp[n+m]
    return rxx

#just prove with in-built   
def autocorr(x): 
    result = np.correlate(x, x, mode='full')
    return result[result.size/2:]

#Parallel or ordinary?
answer = int(raw_input('Non-arallel = 0, parallel = 1 '))

if answer == 0:
    print 'Non-parallel calc was started'
    start = time.time()

    rxx = rxx_func(magn)

    end = time.time()
    calc_time = end - start

    time_string = 'Non-parallel: N = %i    T = %f\n'%(length,calc_time)


else:
    print 'Parallel calc was started'
    ppservers = ()
    ncp = 4
    job_server = pp.Server(ncp, ppservers=ppservers)
    print "Starting pp with", job_server.get_ncpus(), "workers"

    arg_n = tuple(magn)
    job = job_server.submit(rxx_func, (arg_n,), (), ())

    start = time.time()

    rxx = job()
    job_server.print_stats()

    end = time.time()
    calc_time = end - start

    time_string = 'Parallel with %i CPUs: N = %i    T = %f\n'%(ncp,length,calc_time)


print (" \n Task for %i terms takes %f seconds for calc" %(length, calc_time))
print (" Max value of Autocorrelation func achieves %f" %(max(rxx)))
print (" And it'll be normalized to 50 \n")

#normalization to 50
norm_const = 50/max(rxx)

proves = autocorr(magn)

for k in xrange(length):
    rxx[k] = rxx[k]*norm_const
    proves[k] = proves[k]*norm_const

#plotting
plt.plot(times, magn)      
plt.plot(times, rxx)        
plt.plot(times, proves,'*')

plt.show()


for j in xrange(length): #saving results
    st = '%f    %f    %f\n'%(times[j], rxx[j], proves[j])
    res_file.write(st)

times_file.write(time_string) #saving calc times for comparsion

first_file.close()
res_file.close()
times_file.close()
```

The program reads datasets from files to lists. Typical datasets look like commented #magn and #time. Real datasets will consist of 20000 lines or more.

I've trying use the "parallel Python" package, but it runs even more slower than non-parallel code.

For example, some results:

> ```
> Non-parallel: N = 20000    T = 74.530000 sec
> Parallel with 2 CPUs: N = 20000    T = 80.229000 sec
> Parallel with 4 CPUs: N = 20000    T = 80.594000 sec
> ```

And I can't figure out why. Maybe I don't understand how it must be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do much python so I might be wrong but to my understanding, this:

```
job = job_server.submit(rxx_func, (arg_n,), (), ())
```

just submits a single job but it doesn't automatically parallelize it. If you want to process the input in parallel you need to submit `n` jobs each working on 1-nth of the input and then combine the results. I think your parallel execution code should look something like this:

```
slice_size = len(magn) / ncp;

# submit a job for each chunk
jobs = [job_server.submit(rxx_func, (magn,(i-1)*slice_size, slice_size), (), ()) for i in xrange(ncp)]

# combine the results into one list, requires #import itertools
rxx = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([job() for job in jobs]))
```

You will have to change your `rxx_func` to accept a start index and a count which defines for how many items it is responsible:

```
def rxx_func(amp, start_index, count):
    N = len(amp)
    rxx = [0]*count

    for m in xrange(start_index, start_index + count - 1):
        for n in xrange(N-m):
            rxx[m]+=amp[n]*amp[n+m]
    return rxx
```

I'm sure there is plenty which can be optimized in the above.

Comment: Yes, your main idea is brilliant and right, thank you. But for this task these usage will provide wrong results, because for one RXX value calculation needs using whole list of terms (all magn list). But every RXX value can be calculated differently, there is no dependance between RXX[1] and RXX[200]. So for now I trying understand how make ParallelPython do this.

Comment: @Mikic: True, I missed that, I changed my example code.

Comment: for unknown (so far) reason I get an error "jobs = [job_server.submit(rxx_func, (magn,(i-1)*slice_size, slice_size), (), ()) for i in ncp]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable". But, as your code is example I should figure it out by myself, because your approach, I think, is quite right and optimization should keeps in that way. Thank you!

Comment: should have been `xrange(ncp)`, fixed

Comment: After a sleepless night I figured out how the program should work. Added correct, in my opinion, code in question. Sadly increase was not as great as I expected (only 2 times), but the fact of proper work encourages. Unfortunately, I can not mark your answer as helpful, "experience" is not enough, but you was absolutely right. Also sorry, don't understand how "itertools" should works.